# how to generate Branch.io deep link in offline?

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

We are integrating Branch.io with our android app. Branch.io is not generating deep link when internet is off. Internet is not required to share content via SMS, how to generate Branch.io deep link in offline?

Comment: You have to access Branch's API in order to generate a deeplink, therefore it cant be done offline

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create links only by appending query parameters and your app key.

It is described here [Branch.io Appending Query Parameters](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/creating-links-other-ways/guide/#appending-query-parameters)

> Start with your Branch domain. http://bnc.lt (or your white labeled
>   one).
>
> Append /a/your_Branch_key. http://bnc.lt/a/your_branch_key
>
> Append the start of query params ‘?’. http://bnc.lt/a/your_branch_key?
>
> [optional] Append the Branch analytics tag.
>   feature=marketing&channel=email&tags[]=drip1&tags[]=welcome
>
> [optional] Append any custom deep link parameters.
>   &user_id=4562&name=Alex&article_id=456
>
> [optional] Append the data parameter (base64 encoded) filled with your
>   Branch $ control parameters. data=ew0KICAgICJoaSI6ImhlbGxvIg0KfQ==

Comment: Just a note about multiple tags. Using "&tags[]=drip1&tags[]=welcome", I get from BranchSDK iOS an array with 3 items [drip1, drip1, welcome]. Using "&tags=drip1&tags=welcome" without [], I get an array with 2 items, as expected.